# Migration Assistant moved files to inaccesible new account, how to get to my old files?

Tags: macos, migration, pc, migration-assistant

I just got a Mac after many years on a PC. Migration Assistant did not work when I was setting up the computer, so I ran it a few minutes later instead.

However, it seems it transferred all my files to a different account which I cannot access. I don't know the password to that account and resetting it didn't help.

1. What is the simplest way to get my old files?
2. Is there a way to merge accounts?
   Alternatively, If I could log in to it, I can just switch to that account.

Update: I restarted my computer and was able to login to the other account. Now I'll delete the default account.

Comment: Resetting passwords with admin access should have worked... I've been able to do that with multiple accounts on my MBP.

Comment: I was now able to get in to it, so I'll go delete first account.

Comment: Excellent! Make sure that you still have at least one account with admin access - you'll need it to be able to install apps & change your system config.